# How did Native Americans defend militarily?

Tags: military, native-americans, defense

I've seen Native Americans as great warriors who charged armies and raided settlements but I haven't heard much about their defensive capabilities. When they were attacked, did they have set up any stationary defenses (i.e. palisades)? Did they make use of any other inherent advantage of defense?

Comment: Were the "Native Americans" really a homogeneous group that can be considered as a single entity with regard to this question? If not, which of the various "Native Americans" groups were you referring to?

Comment: Sorry my question is broad. I'm using this information to draft a video game loosely based on the conflict between the Native Americans and Colonists so the particular group doesn't matter. I searched for the most prominent of groups (Aztec, Mayan, Cherokee) and only found that the Aztecs built fortifications but the Wikipedia page didn't describe what kinds of fortifications were built.

Comment: You've seen them where? You have a time machine, or crystal ball maybe?

Comment: I don't know, actually. I think that popular culture might have propagated this picture.

Comment: By and large, the Native North American Indian nations were either passive or aggressive attackers. They never really developed defensive techniques, excepting to defend by attacking, There were tribes who defended, such as some of the Pueblo tribes, but for the most part, they did not 'defend' as you are thinking.

Comment: Even if they didn't build fortifications, I'm trying to find anything I can about Native American defense strategies. Did they use their structures' height for safety?

Comment: Concur with Steve Bird; Native Americans inhabited a continent larger than Europe and included may diverse nations, economies, strategies, etc.  If I asked how Europeans defended, would the answer be the same for Lapplanders as for Turks? Swiss? British? French? Question is too broad.

Comment: I think this scenario might be a bit different because while Europeans had defenses all over the place, Native Americans, from what I've read here so far and on the internet, do not. I guess I should change my question then to ask for an example of a Native American fortification.

Comment: @JPtheK9: For defenses, see any of the cliff dwellers (Mesa Verde, Canyon de Chelly, etc) or pueblos like Acoma, Zuni, &c.

Comment: The problem I see people having with the question could be easily fixed simply by picking a tribe, or even a cultural group of tribes. You probably have an image in your head; simply tell us what it is. For example, the "civilized tribes" of the Southeast were settled farmers, and thus an assailant knew where to find them at all times. The Commanche were a nomadic nation like the Mongols, and thus didn't have much of anything for an enemy to attack outside of their buffalo. The Siouxan peoples were sort of a mix of the two.

Comment: The group I have in mind most is the one that lived in Machu Picchu, the Inca empire. Machu Picchu seems like a place that could be defended extremely well so did they make any efforts to do so? If not, what about the Pueblo?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztalan_State_Park  Had a walled city in ancient Wisconsin

Comment: @JPtheK9 Could forests be considered natural fortifications? From what I've read about the American Revolution, the British did not make much use of forests as natural cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the 1720 to 1765 time period. If attacked by a superior force, the typical response would be to flee. The Indians did not use fortifications to any extent. They would hide their villages in inaccessible areas with approaches that were easily watched.

Comment: Great opinion. Backed up by what, exactly?

Comment: Backed up by video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kVFs6RM33E